# How to set Google Calendar in Gmail above chat?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar, chat

If the chat window is too long, then its hard to see the calendar at the bottom of the chat. This makes it difficult to see the calendar and often miss the alerts given by calendar by making the font bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is the chat window being too large, move it to the right side by using the corresponding Labs feature "Right-side chat". Then, the calendar will always be visible on the left directly below the labels.

Comment: I know that option, however I do not want to shift my chat window horizontally i.e. to right.

Comment: Oh, alright. It doesn't seem to take too much space though on a normal monitor. What's your concern about shifting it to the right?

Comment: If the chat window is too long, then its hard to see the calender at the bottom of the chat. The only option I have is to scroll down and then see. If my calender is above chat then its easy for me to have a quick glance as I don't have to scroll down to see my calender.

Answer (score 4):

Enable "Navbar drag and drop" in Settings → Labs and then just drag and drop.

Comment: I can drag it, however I need to do it everytime I open the gmail. Every time I open gmail the position of calender is again at the bottom of the chat.

Comment: Strange. I don't know if it has always been like that. I posted the problem in the feedback form, maybe you can do the same?